# ValueError: 'myproject.sock' is not a socket

Tags: python-3.x, nginx, flask, gunicorn

Через команду:

```
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 wsgi:app
```

Запускается и по адресу все работает. Но если провести манипуляции:

```
sudo systemctl start myproject
sudo systemctl enable myproject
sudo systemctl status myproject
```

То выпадает ошибка (USER, IP_ADR, VDS, MY_PROJECT - тут переименованы):

```
● myproject.service - Gunicorn instance to serve myproject
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/myproject.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2022-03-29 16:28:54 MSK; 7s ago
 Main PID: 589 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
мар 29 16:28:54 VDS.ru gunicorn[589]:     self.start()
мар 29 16:28:54 VDS.ru gunicorn[589]:   File "/home/USER/MY_PROJECT/myprojectenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 155, in s
мар 29 16:28:54 VDS.ru gunicorn[589]:     self.LISTENERS = sock.create_sockets(self.cfg, self.log, fds)
мар 29 16:28:54 VDS.ru gunicorn[589]:   File "/home/USER/MY_PROJECT/myprojectenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/sock.py", line 184, in crea
мар 29 16:28:54 VDS.ru gunicorn[589]:     sock = sock_type(addr, conf, log)
мар 29 16:28:54 VDS.ru gunicorn[589]:   File "/home/USER/MY_PROJECT/myprojectenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gunicorn/sock.py", line 116, in __in
мар 29 16:28:54 VDS.ru gunicorn[589]:     raise ValueError("%r is not a socket" % addr)
мар 29 16:28:54 VDS.ru gunicorn[589]: ValueError: 'myproject.sock' is not a socket
мар 29 16:28:54 VDS.ru systemd[1]: myproject.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
мар 29 16:28:54 VDS.ru systemd[1]: myproject.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Информация:

- Заранее: да, права дал 777, т.к. думал что не хватает прав для для файла - потом уберу как заработает

> nano /etc/systemd/system/myproject.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn instance to serve myproject
After=network.target

[Service]
User=USER
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/USER/MY_PROJECT
Environment="PATH=/home/USER/MY_PROJECT/myprojectenv/bin"
ExecStart=/home/USER/MY_PROJECT/myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:myproject.sock -m 777 wsgi:app
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

> nano /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/myproject

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name IP_ADR;

    location / {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/home/USER/MY_PROJECT/myproject.sock;
return 301 https://$host:443$request_uri;
    }
}
```

**В чем проблема может быть?**